# how to display data from api dio, in provider and call it

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

how to display data from api dio, in provider and call it

Myapi config

```
static Future<ListWisata?> getWisata() async {
    Response? result;
    try {
      result = await Dio().get('https://windramayu-api-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/');
      print('getWisata: ${result.data}');
    } catch (e) {
      (e.toString());
    }
    if (result != null) {
      return ListWisata.fromJson(result.data);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

my json code  contains data maps of tourist locations

```
{
  "datawisata": [
    {
      "about": "Sebagai tempat wisata yang menarik dan unik, Wisata Pohon Randu Gede memiliki cerita tersendiri. Konon taman wisata yang satu ini merupakan pohon mistis yang seringkali dijadikan sebagai spot gambar yang kekinian. Karena pohon randu gede sudah ada sejak ribuan tahun lalu dengan ketinggian sekitar 100 meter dan diameter sekitar 20 meter.",
      "alamat": "Jl. Letnan Sutejo, Margadadi, Kec. Indramayu, Kab. Indramayu, Jawa Barat.",
      "hari": "Setiap Hari",
      "id": 1,
      "img": [
        "https://www.javatravel.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Wisata-Pohon-Randu-Gede-1.jpg",
        "https://www.javatravel.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Wisata-Pohon-Randu-Gede-1.jpg"
      ],
      "jam": "24 Jam",
      "kategori": "Wisata Alam",
      "lat": -6.324085360441674,
      "lng": 108.32296841478009,
      "nama": "Pohon Randu Gede",
      "tiket": "Gratis"
    },
    {
      "about": "Destinasi alam ini selalu ramai setiap akhir pekan dan musim liburan. Lokasinya yang tak jauh dari jantung kota sehingga mudah bagi wisatawan menemukannya. Di sisi lain pesona alam Pantai karangsong memang tidak bisa ditolak keindahannya. Anda akan menemukan keunikan wisata ini, yaitu pantai yang diselimuti hutan mangrov.",
      "alamat": "Jl. Wanasari, Karangsong, Kec. Indramayu, Kabupaten Indramayu, Jawa Barat",
      "hari": "Setiap Hari",
      "id": 2,
      "img": [
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pantai+Karangsong/@-6.3057331,108.3685935,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipNx8CI_LcVwFK-CGCTM5c-8ggyzAi3T_q7BjfPt!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipNx8CI_LcVwFK-CGCTM5c-8ggyzAi3T_q7BjfPt%3Dw396-h298-k-no!7i4624!8i3472!4m15!1m7!3m6!1s0x2e6ebc4872ce9051:0x488988f64087588f!2sPantai+Karangsong!8m2!3d-6.3057331!4d108.3685935!10e4!3m6!1s0x2e6ebc4872ce9051:0x488988f64087588f!8m2!3d-6.3057331!4d108.3685935!14m1!1BCgIgAQ#",
        "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pantai+Karangsong/@-6.3057437,108.3686025,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipPxkDxDXcfVdLxDh-GILyccKLwaQSFNbaqodws!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPxkDxDXcfVdLxDh-GILyccKLwaQSFNbaqodws%3Dw203-h152-k-no!7i4624!8i3468!4m15!1m7!3m6!1s0x2e6ebc4872ce9051:0x488988f64087588f!2sPantai+Karangsong!8m2!3d-6.3057331!4d108.3685935!10e4!3m6!1s0x2e6ebc4872ce9051:0x488988f64087588f!8m2!3d-6.3057331!4d108.3685935!14m1!1BCgIgAQ#"
      ],
      "jam": "08:00 - 17:00 WIB Senin - Jumat\\n07:00 - 18:00 WIB Sabtu & Minggu",
      "kategori": "Wisata Alam",
      "lat": -6.305599800906916,
      "lng": 108.36857204218629,
      "nama": "Pantai Karangsong",
      "tiket": "'1000'"
    },
   ]
}
```

my model data i create with app.quicktype

```
class ListWisata {
    ListWisata({
        this.datawisata,
    });

    List<Datawisata>? datawisata;

    factory ListWisata.fromRawJson(String str) => ListWisata.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory ListWisata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ListWisata(
        datawisata: json["datawisata"] == null ? null : List<Datawisata>.from(json["datawisata"].map((x) => Datawisata.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "datawisata": datawisata == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(datawisata!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datawisata {
  String? about;
  String? alamat;
  String? hari;
  int? id;
  List<String>? img;
  String? jam;
  String? kategori;
  double? lat;
  double? lng;
  String? nama;
  String? tiket;
  
  Datawisata({
    this.about,
    this.alamat,
    this.hari,
    this.id,
    this.img,
    this.jam,
    this.kategori,
    this.lat,
    this.lng,
    this.nama,
    this.tiket,
  });

  factory Datawisata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datawisata(
        about: json["about"] == null ? null : json["about"],
        alamat: json["alamat"] == null ? null : json["alamat"],
        hari: json["hari"] == null ? null : json["hari"],
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        img: json["img"] == null
            ? null
            : List<String>.from(json["img"].map((x) => x)),
        jam: json["jam"] == null ? null : json["jam"],
        kategori: json["kategori"] == null ? null : json["kategori"],
        lat: json["lat"] == null ? null : json["lat"].toDouble(),
        lng: json["lng"] == null ? null : json["lng"].toDouble(),
        nama: json["nama"] == null ? null : json["nama"],
        tiket: json["tiket"] == null ? null : json["tiket"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "about": about == null ? null : about,
        "alamat": alamat == null ? null : alamat,
        "hari": hari == null ? null : hari,
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "img": img == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(img!.map((x) => x)),
        "jam": jam == null ? null : jam,
        "kategori": kategori == null ? null : kategori,
        "lat": lat == null ? null : lat,
        "lng": lng == null ? null : lng,
        "nama": nama == null ? null : nama,
        "tiket": tiket == null ? null : tiket,
      };
}
```

I'm trying to get back a list of data from an API call and display it through the provider
my provider

```
class HomeViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<ListWisata> _wisata = [];
  List get wisatalist => _wisata;

  Future<void> getWisatas() async {
    final c = await WisataApi.getWisata();
    _wisata = c!.datawisata!.cast<ListWisata>();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

n i call it like this

```
ListView.builder(
   itemCount: modelView.wisatalist.length,
   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   shrinkWrap: true,
   physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     return GestureDetector(
        child: BoxWisata(
        h: 100.0,
        w: 100.0,
        fs: 13,
        title: modelview.wisatalist[index].nama,
        img:
        "https://picsum.photos/id/0/400/300",
          ),
```

IDK no how to get n call the api

Answer (score 0):

Put your *getWisata()* function to the provider file

```
class WisataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
Future<ListWisata?> getWisata() async {
Response? result;
try {
  result = await Dio().get(
      'https://windramayu-api-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/');
  print('getWisata: ${result.data}');
} catch (e) {
  (e.toString());
}
if (result != null) {
  return ListWisata.fromJson(result.data);
}
return null;
}
}
```

And then call it in the main page

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var provider = Provider.of<WisataProvider>(context);
return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: provider.getWisata(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: modelView.wisatalist.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final data = modelview.wisatalist[index];
          return GestureDetector(
            child: BoxWisata(
              h: 100.0,
              w: 100.0,
              fs: 13,
              title: data.nama,
              img: "https://picsum.photos/id/0/400/300",
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
  );
 }
 }
```

I hope this is will help you :)

Comment: how u add modelview ? u not declar it in provider n main page?

i still don't get it

Answer (score 0):

https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 use api,
pub dev: provider and dio

create HomePage and paste code as it is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:techstrock2/demoApi/dio_s.dart';
import 'package:techstrock2/demoApi/imageapiview.dart';

class freeapi extends StatefulWidget {
  const freeapi({super.key});

  @override
  State<freeapi> createState() => _freeapiState();
}

class _freeapiState extends State<freeapi> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<imageprovider>().imageapi();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imageP = context.watch<imageprovider>();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            onChanged: (query) {
              context.read<imageprovider>().filterImages(query);
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: imageP.filteredImage.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Image.network(imageP.filteredImage[index].avatar!),
                    title: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(imageP.filteredImage[index].firstName!),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Text(imageP.filteredImage[index].lastName!),
                      ],
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(imageP.filteredImage[index].email!),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

create Provider Page and paste code as it is.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:techstrock2/demoApi/usemodal.dart';

import 'usermodal.dart';

class imageprovider with ChangeNotifier {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  List<Data> image = [];
  List<Data> filteredImage = [];
  imageapi() async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.data);
        imagedata images = imagedata.fromJson(response.data);
        image.addAll(images.data!);
        filteredImage.addAll(images.data!);
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        print("error");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  // Function to filter images based on search query
  void filterImages(String query) {
    filteredImage.clear();
    if (query.isEmpty) {
      filteredImage.addAll(image);
    } else {
      query = query.toLowerCase();
      filteredImage.addAll(image.where((data) {
        return data.firstName!.toLowerCase().contains(query) ||
            data.lastName!.toLowerCase().contains(query);
      }));
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

create modal page and paste code as it is.

```
class imagedata {
  int? page;
  int? perPage;
  int? total;
  int? totalPages;
  List<Data>? data;
  Support? support;

  imagedata(
      {this.page,
      this.perPage,
      this.total,
      this.totalPages,
      this.data,
      this.support});

  imagedata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    page = json['page'];
    perPage = json['per_page'];
    total = json['total'];
    totalPages = json['total_pages'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    support =
        json['support'] != null ? new Support.fromJson(json['support']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['page'] = this.page;
    data['per_page'] = this.perPage;
    data['total'] = this.total;
    data['total_pages'] = this.totalPages;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.support != null) {
      data['support'] = this.support!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int? id;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? avatar;

  Data({this.id, this.email, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.avatar});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    data['first_name'] = this.firstName;
    data['last_name'] = this.lastName;
    data['avatar'] = this.avatar;
    return data;
  }
}

class Support {
  String? url;
  String? text;

  Support({this.url, this.text});

  Support.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    url = json['url'];
    text = json['text'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['text'] = this.text;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).